# Set a dynamic image on prototype cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swiftyuserdefaults

I want to display on "Profile" cell the image of the user.
To do that I supposed to use the same snippet that solve the profile load.

First of all I declared an `UIImageView!` variable:

```
var accountimage: UIImageView!
```

Then, in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I downloaded by `UserDefaults` constructor the Avatar:

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell.backgroundColor? = UIColor(red: 236/255,green: 239/255,blue: 240/255,alpha: 1)
    let myFont: UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next Condensed", size: 22.0)
    if let aFont = myFont {
        cell.textLabel?.font = aFont
        //load account image
        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") != nil{
            let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") as! Data
            let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: decoded)
            accountimage.image = decodedTeams as? UIImage
            cell.imageView?.image = accountimage.image
        } else
        {
            accountimage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user.png")
            cell.imageView?.image = accountimage.image
        }
}
}
```

Debugger says this on `accountimage.image = decodedTeams as? UIImage` line:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

---

**Edit**

Here a screen of my `Main.Storyboard` in case should be helpful:

[image: Main.Storyboard]

Comment: `let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") as! Data` are you **sure** this isn't `nil`? If that's not the case, you should use `as?` instead of `as!`.

Comment: I maked a condiction.. In any case if I haven't an image setted, There's a default image to solve the nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you made a small mistake on this code

`let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") as! Data`

**as!**means forced conversion but may fail.

Comment: If I do this the debbugger says: "Value of optional type 'Data?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?" on 'decodedTeams' line. So I do as xcode tell me to do and use value '(decoded)' to (decoded!). In the end The result is the same: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: I also tryied to keep 'as!' on "accountimage.image = (decodedTeams as! UIImage)" but The result is the same: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Just make a change and check where is the error,try this
```let decoded  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "profile_avatar") as? Data
if let data = decoded {
    //first check
    let decodedTeams = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? UIImage
    if let image = decodedTeams {
        // second check
    }
}else {
    
}
```